# Submit Form and it's Data to Outside URL as well as redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make a login form on the front end of my site that will take the username and password and submit to an outside URL (a portal for the customers). I want the data they sumbit to the form on my website to pass to the new URL with the portal and attempt to log them in. Right now, nothing is happening and I can't figure out what is happening. Currently, when I submit the form, it just appends to my current URL with the POST data from the form it doesnt attempt to send the data to the outside URL neither does it re direct.

HTML:

```
<form id="redirect-form">
 <p class="mbn"><input type="text" name="loginid" placeholder="username" /></p>
 <p class="mbn"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>
 <p> <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:register()">Sign In</button></p>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function register() {
    form=document.getElementById('redirect-form');
    form.target='_blank';
    form.action='https://pathtomyportal.com';
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Set `method="post"` on the form

Comment: That's exactly what a form does without any javascript at all, when you add an `action` attribute. You should be using a POST method as well.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you are adding the action, target, and submitting the form via JS? Why not just add those attributes to the HTML?

Comment: added the method="post" to the form and still not getting the correct result =/

Comment: <form action="http://<outsideURL>" method="post">

Comment: taking me to the outside URL now but not sending the Data

Comment: How are you reading data from server side? Add server side code for reading data from request

Answer (score 0):

Change your form method to **POST**.

```
<form id="redirect-form" method="POST">
 <p class="mbn"><input type="text" name="loginid" placeholder="username" /></p>
 <p class="mbn"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></p>
 <p> <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:register()">Sign In</button></p>
</form>
```

Your Javascript is valid and working fine for me. It sending `post` data to server side.